# MS Access query problem, with criteria in short text field

Tags: ms-access-2010

I am trying to make a query to only list computers with over 500 MB of ram, the RAM field is short text with both "MB" and "GB" at the end of the string. the problem i am having is I cant seem to code the expression right and I keep having various errors on everything i have tried so far.

I'm not looking for the solution but it would be appreciated or point me in the direction of what I should read up on. Thanks in advance

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Can you post an example of your input and expected output? And what code have you already tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the query, you can filter on the *value* alone and on *MB/GB*:

```
Where (Val([RAM]) >= 500 And InStr([RAM], "MB") > 0) Or (Val([RAM]) >= 0.5 And InStr([RAM], "GB") > 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, only thing  had to do was change Value to Val and it worked :)..